# How to find the correct solution of the minimum positive period of the trigonometric function in one step?

Tags: functions

Find the minimum positive period of the following trigonometric function：

[image]

Use this method as follows:

```
In[9]:= FunctionPeriod[-Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x + \[Pi]/4] + 
  6 Sin[x] Cos[x] - 2 Cos[x]^2 + 1, x, Reals]

Out[9]= 2 \[Pi]
```

The correct answer for the minimum positive period should be  `\[Pi]`

Because:

```
In[11]:= TrigExpand[-Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x + \[Pi]/4] + 6 Sin[x] Cos[x] - 
  2 Cos[x]^2 + 1]

Out[11]= -2 Cos[x]^2 + 4 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 2 Sin[x]^2

In[12]:= TrigFactor[%]

Out[12]= -2 Sqrt[2] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 2 x]

In[13]:= FunctionPeriod[%, x, Reals]

Out[13]= \[Pi]
```

So the  answer for the minimum positive period is `\[Pi]`

Comment: Please do not contain `In[...]` and  `Out[...]` in the code. It is not convenient for reader to copy the code to run.

Comment: Document of `FunctionPeriod` never claims it'll find the minimal positive period.

Comment: `-Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x + \[Pi]/4] +   6 Sin[x] Cos[x] - 2 Cos[x]^2 + 1 // FullSimplify // FunctionPeriod[#, x]&`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
f[x_] = -Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x + Pi/4] + 6 Sin[x] Cos[x] - 2 (Cos[x])^2 + 
   1;
g = FullSimplify[TrigExpand[f[x]]]
FunctionPeriod[g, x]
```

> `\[Pi]`

Comment: You can leave off the TrigExpand... FunctionPeriod[FullSimplifyf[x]],x] is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. OP wants `one step`. I use `TrigExpand`.

Comment: My point was that you use both FullSimplify and TrigExpand. The latter is not necessary. But it's not a big deal!